# Html.HiddenFor value property not getting set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewdata, html.hiddenfor

I could have used

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=> ViewData["crn"])
```

but, I get,

`<input id="ViewData_crn_" name="ViewData[crn]" type="hidden" value="500" />`

To somehow circumvent that issue(`id=ViewData_crn_ and name=ViewData[crn]`), I tried doing the following, but the "value" attribute isn't getting set.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CRN, new { @value="1"})
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CRN, new { @Value="1"})
```

generates

```
<input id="CRN" name="CRN" type="hidden" value="" />
<input Value="500" id="CRN" name="CRN" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Am I doing anything wrong??
Thanks

Comment: I don't think HiddenFor knows how to "read" values from ViewData. You can use Html.Hidden("fieldName", ViewData["crn"])

Comment: For anyone using MVC 4 please see @Gudradain answer below.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/HTML-HiddenFor-set-value-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have you tried using a view model instead of ViewData? Strongly typed helpers that end with `For` and take a lambda expression cannot work with weakly typed structures such as `ViewData`.

Personally I don't use ViewData/ViewBag. I define view models and have my controller actions pass those view models to my views.

For example in your case I would define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string CRN { get; set; }
}
```

have my controller action populate this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        CRN = "foo bar"
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and then have my strongly typed view simply use an `EditorFor` helper:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CRN)
```

which would generate me:

```
<input id="CRN" name="CRN" type="hidden" value="foo bar" />
```

in the resulting HTML.

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old answer, but wouldn't you want to use hiddenfor instead of editorfor if you want the input to be hidden.

Comment: @ScottAdams, I have decorated the CRN property on my view model with the `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` attribute which will make the EditorFor helper generate a hidden field.

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccionActual)` not working

Answer (score 55):

The following will work in MVC 4

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CRN, new { @Value = "1" });
```

@Value property is case sensitive. **You need a capital 'V' on @Value**.

Here is my model

```
public int CRN { get; set; }
```

Here is what is output in html when you look in the browser

```
<input value="1" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CRN must be a number." data-val-required="The CRN field is required." id="CRN" name="CRN" type="hidden" value="1"/>
```

Here is my method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
  int crn = viewModel.CRN;
}
```

Comment: This saved me so much frustration. `HiddenFor(t => t.Id)` doesn't work.  Using `@value = Model.Id` didn't work. I had to use `@Value` - the capital `V` is apparently important. This is awful and must be a bug.

Comment: Yes the capital V is important. Also, the @ is not required it seems. Both @Value and just Value works for me.

Comment: I am still new to MVC but where is you "MyMethod" The rest of the code I have is similar to yours but I don't know where your method goes.

Comment: @mgrenier It is simply a method in the controller. In this case, it is the method that will receive the form data after you post it from your browser.

Comment: Darin's answer is best, but this does work @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CRN); I have used that when I had a method with a specific value that I binded to my model before it sent back to display the view thus for me comments.tblTipsId = id; return View(comments);    Then on the page is @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.tblTipsId)

Comment: I have been using MVC for a few years now and I just realised that HiddenFor doesn't set value. That's a shame. Thanks for the answer. This really helped me.

Answer (score 5):

I believe there is a simpler solution.
You must use `Html.Hidden` instead of `Html.HiddenFor`. Look:

```
@Html.Hidden("CRN", ViewData["crn"]);
```

This will create an `INPUT` tag of `type="hidden"`, with `id="CRN"` and `name="CRN"`, and the correct value inside the `value` attribute.

Hope it helps!

Comment: While this may appear simpler than [Darin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6850618/61654) it utilizes magic strings and therefore increases potential for problems during refactoring etc.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind the second parameter to @Html.HiddenFor will only be used to set the value when it can't find route or model data matching the field. Darin is correct, use view model.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to use @Html.TextboxFor but place it in a div that is hidden with style.
Example:
In View:

`<div style="display:none">
@Html.TextboxFor(x=>x.CRN)
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

```
@{
   Model.CRN = ViewBag.CRN;
}

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CRN)
```