# MVC lambda does not work on RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

on one page i am rendering other view this way:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Angebotspruefung", new ViewDataDictionary {{ "OpportunityEditModel", Model }} }); %>
```

and on rendered view I retrive this model this way:

```
<% 
    OpportunityDetailsEditModel model = (OpportunityDetailsEditModel)ViewData["OpportunityEditModel"];    
%>
```

and there is sth very very wird, i can acces properties with `<%= model.Property %>` but lambda does't work , so this won't work

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property) %>
```

Comment: won't work in what way? What compile/run-time time error are you having? Is there a model declared on the view where you're doing the  `HiddenFor`?

Comment: there are no problem with compiliation, just there are null values

Comment: the following thread shows what you need to do. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850174/html-hiddenfor-value-property-not-getting-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamda expression Helpers works only with strongly typed views. Intead of passing ViewData, make your Partial View Strongly typed and pass to Html.RenderPartial the Object Model. Then, you will have the expected functionality with lambda.

```
 <%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property) %>
```

In this code above m is suposed to be the model from its view, so the helper tries to render the control, but its view has no Model, its setted manually by an object, then the reflection from control render fails.

EDIT:

RenderPartial has an overload that gives you the ability of pass the model as parameter, take a look here:

[RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Hopes its help your!

Comment: how can I pass to partialView object model?

Comment: @kosnkov I edited the comment! All the information is above! Hopes its help you! :)